# Is it possible fade instead of scroll using jquery ui tools scrollable?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, fade, scrollable

I know this might be a mad question given this tool is called 'scrollable', but does anyone know if its possible to fade the elements instead of scroll?

I'm using [Jquery Ui Tools Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/one-sized.html) and I'm wondering if the effect can be changed to fade instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you link to mentions:

> This demo continues from this [tabs demo](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/skins.html) and makes it scrollable.

The effect used in the tabs demo is a fade.

Comment: @aligreene Whoops. I fixed the broken link in the answer now.